# android error 495 while downloading application , why is there no solution for it?

Tags: samsung, samsung-galaxy-ace

tried almost every solution but faced very frequently.
Android should deliver a fix for it and at least show more details on the failure.
almost could not download from weeks due to 495 error.

Answer (score 0):

Well, what you can try following methods:

Step 1. Clearing Cache and Clear Data stored over the Google Play Store:

Go to Settings -> Click on Application Manager or Apps -> Open “All” apps

If that still doesn't helps you:

Step 2. Clear Cache and Data for Google Play Service Framework - For clearing the cache and data of frame work you can use the same steps mentioned above, what you only need to do is search for the Google Play Services app and clear its cache and data stored.

If you still encounter the error then head over to Step 3

Step 3.Remove Gmail Account and Add it again:

Head over to Settings>Accounts and sync> Tap over the Google account> Tap over Remove account. Once done again clear the cache and the data of Google Play Service app which I already mentioned over STEP2. Once you cleared everything up add the google account again.